# Tangent vectors acting on composition of two functions

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I came across the following question (I'm reading "A Visual Introduction to Differential Forms and Calculus on Manifolds"):

> For a mapping $\phi : M \mapsto N$ and a function $f : N \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, show that $v_p[f \circ \phi] = (T_p \phi \cdot v_p)_{\phi(p)} [f].$ $M,N$ manifolds and $v_p$ a tangent vector at $p$.

Now I know the from the definition of the tangent vector operator we have:

$$
v_p[f \circ \phi]  = \frac{d}{dt} (f(\phi(p + tv_p)) \rvert_{t=0}
$$

However from here I don't know how to proceed. I can see that the LHS is essential sending a real number to real number but I don't quite get what the RHS is doing.

Comment: What $v_p$ is ?

Comment: @Vajra $v_p$ is a tangent vector at $p \in M$ (i.e. an element of the the tangent space at $p \in M$).

Comment: $p+tv_p$ makes sense on $R^n$, not on a general manifold $M$, (unless you are using a local coordinate system implicitly?)